# How does Linux allow modifying a PDF while open in a PDF viewer?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, pdf

When I am working with graphs in `R`, I try to output them directly into PDF. For e.g. the code for creating a graph is as follows.

```
library(ggplot2)
levels_fp = ggplot(data=df_forest_2,
    aes(x = levels,y=center, ymin=lower, ymax=upper))+
    geom_pointrange(aes(col=levels))+
    geom_hline(aes(fill=levels),yintercept =1, linetype=2)+
    xlab('Outcomes Evaluated')+ geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper,col=levels),width=0.2,cex=1)+ 
    facet_wrap(~outcome,strip.position="top",nrow=1,scales = "free_x") + theme(
    axis.title = element_text(size = 18),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 14),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 16),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 16),
  
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    legend.box.background = element_rect(),axis.text.x = element_blank(), strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14)
  ) + ylab("Odds Ratio")+labs(col="Interventions")

pdf(file="Forest_levels_2.pdf", width=12,height =12 ) 
levels_fp
dev.off()
```

The thing I am intrigued about is: suppose I have kept the pdf (which I output from the previous step, namely **Forest_levels_2.pdf**) open in a PDF viewer. Then, if I run the code again, the file gets output and overwrites the previous PDF, and the output in PDF viewer is also instantly changed.

But if I try to do the same in Windows, that is I have kept the PDF open with a PDF viewer, and I try to run the code, the following error will come --> **cannot access pdf**. Why there is a difference in behavior in Linux (I am working with Ubuntu 20.04)?

Adding the output of the Windows error

```
Error in pdf(file = "Forest_levels_2.pdf", width = 12, height = 12) : 
  cannot open file 'Forest_levels_2.pdf'
```

In order to remove some variables, I tried to download the Evince PDF viewer for windows (Evince 2.32) and then opened the PDF using Evince in Windows and did the same experiment again.

Guess what happened!?!

I was able to successfully modify the open PDF in Windows. Evince works same in both Ubuntu and Windows. So probably, it is more dependent on the property of PDF viewer also.

Comment: If I do understand you correctly your are aware of the specific file monitoring capabilities of the particular PDF viewer, but wonder if there is a fundamental difference on the file system level? Is the Windows behaviour temporary, or does it crash the viewer? Did you try it with different viewers?  Who issues the error? R or the PDF viewer?

Comment: @DonQuestion In windows it does not crash the PDF viewer, but it will never ever allow ```R``` to write in it when it is open. I have not tried with different viewer in Windows. Will do it. The error is issued by ```R``` that the file is unable to be accessed in Windows. In Ubuntu, no such error surfaces.

Comment: I think you discovered something very interesting and to share it with a greater audience you should edit your initial qestion. Maybe add the error message to it, e.g.': Cannot access pdf under Windows while Linux allows writes to an open PDF file?

Comment: @DonQuestion Ok will do that

Comment: If I remember correctly, this is a feature of Evince (the PDF viewer in Ubuntu).

Comment: Are you *sure* that the difference is between Windows and Linux? Have you eliminated all other variables? Are you using the same PDF viewer in both cases?

Comment: @DonQuestion I have added the error of  PDF Viewer in Windows

Comment: @JörgWMittag I have answered your question in the new edit

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is a function of the PDF viewer you are using.

I suspect, the PDF viewer opens the file, and then reads/processes the contents.  It does not have to close the file, but it might.

Next, it sets up an [`inotify`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html), meaning that if someone writes to the file, your PDF viewer will be notified.

When you wrote to the file, your PDF viewer received a signal that the file it was watching changed.  This gives the PDF viewer a chance to re-read the file and re-process the contents.

Something similar is possible in Windows, but the PDF viewer you're using simply hasn't implemented that.  When your Windows PDF viewer opens a PDF, it gets exclusive access by default to the PDF file which will cause another program to get an error when they attempt to open the file for writing. The viewer would have to make system calls to explicitly drop the exclusive access in order to operate in a similar manner to the linux version.

---

I found an interesting [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking) on File locking.  It says:

> Windows inherits the semantics of share-access controls from the MS-DOS system, where sharing was introduced in MS-DOS 3.3 . Thus, an application must explicitly allow sharing when it opens a file; otherwise it has exclusive read, write, and delete access to the file until closed (other types of access, such as those to retrieve the attributes of a file are allowed.)

It also says:

> Unix-like operating systems (including Linux and Apple's macOS) do not normally automatically lock open files.

Comment: The latter part is the most significant in my mind; by default, Windows locks open files, which causes the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: The PDF viewer I was using in Windows was Adobe Acrobat DC and in Ubuntu it was Document Viewer.

Comment: Note that there are programs that behave like Document Viewer on Windows. A good example is nodemon which monitors your javascript files for changes and restart your node.js program when you save any file. Another example is the react-scripts script that comes with React.js which recompiles your React app and reloads the browser every time you save any file in your project.

Comment: I tried to find a decent PDF viewer that allowed this under Windows, when I still used that OS regularly (FoxIt used to allow overwriting but started locking the file about 6 years ago). I was compiling LaTeX, inspecting, tweaking, and recompiling. All the ones I found were outdated ports of Linux viewers. Windows has a range of options for file locking; it's even possible to prevent a file from being *copied* while open (and of course software that does that is exactly the same software that make might you want to take a sudden snapshot).

Comment: The Adobe reader behaviour is a deliberate design choice: The pdf file is locked and only partly read into memory. This allows Reader to handle very large pdf files.  Evince on the other hand will read the whole file into memory, which can create problems on systems which are short on RAM.  (from memory, though I recall the source seemed a reliable one: adobe developers or similar)

Comment: That point about file locking is rather significant. In most cases, you cannot replace an open file on Windows because of this behavior (and this is why you have to reboot for every last little OS update on Windows), but you can pretty much always do so on UNIX-like systems (possibly even if the file is locked depending on the specifics).

Comment: @ChrisH SumatraPDF is a PDF viewer for windows that does not lock the PDF files, if it's of any interest.

Comment: Adding to [@VisualMelon's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/606588/how-does-linux-allow-modifying-a-pdf-while-open-in-a-pdf-viewer#comment1132515_606592), SumatraPDF is installed with RStudio, so it might actually be already available on the OP's system. SumatraPDF is my personal non-locking PDF viewer of choice for viewing PDFs while editing them (using R or LaTeX).

Comment: @VisualMelon I used it for a while, but now only use Windows in a vm for specialist software.  Another option is the viewer built in to most browsers

Comment: @JamesK Though there's no inherent reason why streaming the file from disk means you have to lock the file, as long as you can detect if the file has been changed out from under you. (You can use a crude algorithm of checking the modify timestamp plus rereading a small portion of what you've already read if you can't depend on notification from the OS.)

Comment: @JamesK It needs it.   I have a [small but very complex PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347014/28808) that chokes Adobe (and most other viewers).

Comment: @JamesK evince does not load the entire file into ram. It simply reads the entire file upon opening so that it can read metadata that may be at the end of the file.

Comment: @JamesK Not really, you can do that w/o locking. Furthermore, I'd argue that it's a bad design choice, overcomplicating things, especially since Adobe Reader by itself is already rather hungry, it's absurd to try to be efficient *there*.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn You could actually try to implement locking and still update w/o restarting on Windows, just the same way you can not implement locking and update with required restarting. The latter is actually becoming more common in the Linux world (e.g. fedora) because otherwise you might have race conditions or inconsistent data. This is not *necessarily* related to locking though, even if this is one technique to avoid inconsistency.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn, ...and on Unixen, the old copies of the files are kept in use, if there's processes running that have them open. Which means that to e.g. update the C library, you still have to restart pretty much every single process on the system to get them use the new version. And that's pretty close to just rebooting anyway. :)

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, but, updates that actually hit everything are typically pretty uncommon, and even if you are dealing with one, restarting all code in userspace is quite often much faster than a full reboot (consider that it's not unusual for servers to take multiple minutes just to POST, not even counting however long the bootloader and kernel startup take).

Comment: It's not just that Linux (and most unix-like OSes) rarely use locking, it's that the doctrine surrounding them is more focussed on files being per-user and unshared, and as a result the locking APIs are comparative newcomers- as are the APIs that advise whether a file or directory has been updated. OTOH, there's well-developed doctrine for how multiple programs should create/open/move files in order to preserve ownership and access rights, which are "minor details" that Windows etc. for a long time preferred to ignore.